# How to install Mendeley on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: python, 22.04

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 and I have been trying to install Mendeley through its .deb installer and the .tar.bz2, but in both cases it throws me a problem with the dependencies:

```
/usr/bin/env: "python": No such file or directory
```

I really liked the experience with the new version of Ubuntu and I would not like to go back, but Mendeley is a program that I use a lot due to my work.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Same question as @Just_Alex

Comment: @Natan The solutions below work but do not allow referencing in libreoffice. Eventually I moved to zotero. I use mendeley in the browser to capture references and periodically sync it to zotero. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Natan, I'm not sure I can post it here, but on github you can find a script to do what the answers below suggest (i.e., repackage mendeley) completely effortless :)

Comment: This question is  no longer relevant, since Mendeley Desktop is no longer available for download and installation.

Comment: @climatestudent, I just downloaded and installed Mendeley Desktop v1.19.8 for Linux from https://www.mendeley.com/autoupdates/installers/1.19.8

Comment: @HalHollis, thanks for noting that and providing the link; I should probably change the above then to say that Mendeley Desktop is no longer officially supported or updated by Mendeley.

Answer (score 10):

When installing Mendeley on Ubuntu 22.04 I was met with the following
error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mendeleydesktop:
 mendeleydesktop depends on python; however:
  Package python is not installed.
```

The following solution worked for me:

0. Check that the command `python` executes Python properly. If you don't have the `python` command, then please install `python-is-python3`.

NOTE: If the version of Python is 2.xx then you can skip steps 2 and 4.

1. Unpack the `.deb` file, remove "python" from its dependencies, and then repack it. I followed the instructions in [@Janus Troelsen's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/383958/164786) in [How do I get apt-get to ignore some dependencies?](https://serverfault.com/questions/250224/how-do-i-get-apt-get-to-ignore-some-dependencies). So modify the third line in the `control` file from:

   ```
   Depends: libc6, python, gconf2, desktop-file-utils
   ```

   to:

   ```
   Depends: libc6, gconf2, desktop-file-utils
   ```
2. And then make a softlink `/usr/bin/python` to indicate `python2`:

   ```
   cd /usr/bin
   sudo mv python python_old
   sudo ln -s python2 python
   ```
3. Install Mendeley with the repacked `.deb` file without errors (I hope).
4. Restore `/usr/bin/python` as before:

   ```
   sudo rm python
   sudo mv python_old python
   ```

I hope my answer is helpful for others in the same situation.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thanks!

Comment: Can someone make this deb file available?

Comment: It works, but does not close. Prompting `ERROR:service_manager_context.cc(171)`

Comment: The libre-writer citation plugin still causes freezing.

Comment: @Just_Alex I felt the same error too, however, I don't know how to resolve this issue yet. It seems like that the error is related to Qt but no ideas more than this. I'll share information if I find a solution.

Comment: Hi @philip , not sure. Running in terminal suggests some possible culprits.1. `distutils package is deprecated` 2. `ERROR:service_manager_context.cc(171)` and 3 `File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1896`

Comment: Thanks, worked fine for me after removing the broken install with `apt --fix-broken install` , installing Python 2 (`apt install python2`) and symlinking it to `python` (`ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /home/$USER/.local/bin/python`)

Comment: can you explain why you needed to backup python?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. I can install the new package without error. But can't open mendeleydesktop. When I click on the icon, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is not such a good idea; I run Mendeley Desktop and it keeps using 12.5% of my CPU power (I have eight processors). I don't know why, maybe it's mining Bitcoin.

---

An easier solution is to install with the generic Linux installer, see [Holger_Gehrke's answer](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474380).

1. Download the generic linux installer and extract in your `$HOME` folder.
2. Run `python3 mendeleydesktop-1.19.8-linux-x86_64/bin/mendeleydesktop`.
3. You can isnstall with `bash mendeleydesktop-1.19.8-linux-x86_64/bin/install-mendeley-link-handler.sh ~/mendeleydesktop-1.19.8-linux-x86_64/`
4. To start Mendeley Desktop I hit win-D and then start typing mendeley.

Comment: thanks it is working

Answer (score 1):

The command `python` is not installed by default on Ubuntu 22.04. Install `python-is-python3` to have a symlink `python` that points to `python3`, and then it is hoped that application works well with the current python version, because Python 2 is not anymore supported on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Installing `python-is-python3` worked perfectly. But before creating the symlink, you need to uninstall Mendeley. If you keep it installed (even though it is not working), it will mess up the `python-is-python3` installation.

Steps:

1. Uninstall `medeleydesktop`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove mendeleydesktop
   ```
2. Install `python-is-python3`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-is-python3 -y
   ```
3. Then install Mendeley again:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i <package_path>
   ```

   where `<package_path>` is the path to Mendeley .deb file.

Comment: This does not resolve the issue. Tried both ppa and .deb file.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was installing the desktop version trough a flatpak

```
flatpak install flathub com.elsevier.MendeleyDesktop
```

```
flatpak run com.elsevier.MendeleyDesktop
```

Downloading and installing it directly from flathub site works fine. I was not able to solve the "python" missing package (and dependences) problem, but this is an acceptable workaround. Since there won´t be a desktop version in the future I dont know if this will be working so far.

Comment: Unfortunately by running this via flatpak I get a very high CPU usage

Comment: it seems like mendeley has been removed from flatpak

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and followed the instructions just to discuss that Mendeley Desktop doesn't link to academic accounts. I tried Mendeley Reference Manager and the installation worked straight away and as I want. I'm guessing the desktop version is old now.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question after trying the new web-based Mendeley reference manager and becoming frustrated with its lack of features compared to the older desktop version.

I ended relying on Docker to install Mendeley Desktop 1.19.8 on my machine, using the image from this github repository: [Mendeley-Docker](https://github.com/javadr/mendeley-docker).

In a nutshell:

```bash
# Make sure docker is installed
docker run hello-world

# Clone repository
git clone https://github.com/javadr/mendeley-docker
cd mendeley-docker

# Build image
./build.sh

# Run image
./run.sh
```

It worked like a charm for me!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Python is only required for the install. And it requires Python 2, because there are some statements like `print "bla"` in the install code.

So you need to do two simple steps:

1. make Python 2 your default python, for instance:

```
sudo apt-get install python2
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python
python --version
> Python 2.7.18
```

2. Install mendeley, but without python dependency (I don't know why that is necessary, but it was for me):

```
sudo dpkg --ignore-depends=python -i Downloads/mendeleydesktop_1.19.8-stable_amd64.deb
```

That's it. You probably want to remove the symlink to Python2 again.

Answer (score -1):

@Just_Alex your solution to repackage after removing python dependency worked for me. Thanks! But it did later complain that it could not find `gconf2`.

I was able to fix that by first running:

```bash
 sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

And then installing the repackaged file.