# 22-04 : Howto install python-gtk2 and python-glade-2 for fslint

Tags: package-management, 22.04

I need python-gtk2 and python-glade-2 for an old app, but when I run dpkg -i I get this (translated), stating I miss python ???

```
sudo dpkg -i python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb python-glade2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb 
Selecting packet python-gtk2 previously deselected.
(reading database... 364958 files et directories already installed.)
Preparation to unpacking python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-gtk2 (2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting packet python-glade2 previously deselected.
Preparation to unpacking python-glade2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-glade2 (2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: dependencies problems prevent configuration of python-gtk2 :
 python-gtk2 depends on python (<< 2.8) ; although :
  Packet python is not installed.
 python-gtk2 depend on python (>= 2.7) ; although :
  Package python is not installed.
 python-gtk2 depend on python:any (>= 2.6.6-7~) ; although :
  Package python is not installed.

dpkg: error when processing python-gtk2 package (--install) :
 dependencies problems - left unconfigured
dpkg: dependencies problems prevent configuration of python-glade2 :
 python-glade2 depends on python (<< 2.8) ; although :
  Package python is not installed.
 python-glade2 depends on python (>= 2.7) ; although :
  Package python is not installed.
 python-glade2 depends on python-gtk2 (= 2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2) ; although :
 Package python-gtk2 is not yet configured.

dpkg: error when processing python-glade2 package (--install) :
 dependencies problems - left unconfigured
Errors were encountered when running :
 python-gtk2
 python-glade2
```

Although :

```
sudo apt list python2.7 --installed
Listing... Done
python2.7/jammy,now 2.7.18-13ubuntu1 amd64  [installed]
```

Please tell me what is wrong there. I did it OK some days ago on a debian11 and I just had to run

```
sudo apt -f install
```

to fix the problem. Instead, when I *apt -f install* here, ubuntu wants to remove the 2 packages instead of fixing the installation.

Thanks for tips. I know this is really not standard thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not as elegant, we now have fslint-unofficial snap in Ubuntu Software center

Answer (score 0):

See Just_Alex's answer at [How to install Mendeley on Ubuntu 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405042/how-to-install-mendeley-on-ubuntu-22-04) which starts with "When installing Mendeley on Ubuntu 22.04 I was met with the following Error :".

He references a detailed answer on https://serverfault.com/a/383958 to remove the `python` dependency from the python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb. You should be able to do the same thing for the python-glade2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb package as well.

Once you've removed the dependency and repackaged the .debs, you should be able to proceed with installing/running your old app.