# Can't install Zenmap on Ubuntu 22.04 due to dependency issues

Tags: apt, package-management, python, dpkg, dependencies

So here's the issue, basically I've gone through some research of dependencies of Zenmap. It relies on the things like Python GTK as [Here](https://nmap.org/download).
But when installing python-gtk using

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb

sudo apt install ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

There are some dependencies issues like

```
seek4samurai@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb 
[sudo] password for seek4samurai: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'python-gtk2' instead of './python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-gtk2 : Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not installable
               Depends: python (>= 2.7) but it is not installable
               Depends: python:any (>= 2.6.6-7~) but it is not installable
               Depends: python-cairo (>= 1.0.2-1.1) but it is not installable
               Depends: python-gobject-2 (>= 2.21.3) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Now I've installed python both version `2.7.18` & `3.10.4`. Though when just typing python in terminal launches the `python 2.7.18`.

Please let me know how to fix this issue. Thanks.

Comment: I there a reason you didn't just use `sudo apt install python-gtk` to install the correct version for your system?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and using the deb packages as listed on many "howtos" simply doesn't work. Python 2.x has been completely phased out and the last thing you want is a bunch of outdated packages on your system. Luckily someone has forked nmap and updated Zenmap to Python 3. You can install from this source fairly easily:

**1. Install prerequisites**

```
$ sudo apt install build-essential checkinstall zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

**2. Get the source code from github**

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ wget https://github.com/nmap/nmap/archive/refs/heads/master.zip -O nmap.zip

$ unzip nmap.zip

$ cd nmap-master
```

**3. Fix Zenmap config file**

There is an error in the current Zenmap config file and if not fixed Zenmap will not be able to find your nmap binary.

```
$ nano zenmap/share/zenmap/config/zenmap.conf
```

Navigate to line 60 and fix the [paths] section. Change this:

```
[paths]
nmap_command_path = ../nmap
ndiff_command_path = ../ndiff/ndiff
```

To this:

```
[paths]
nmap_command_path = nmap
ndiff_command_path = ndiff
```

*If you have already gotten everything installed but Zenmap can’t find nmap, you can do the same fix on the file in your home folder:*

```
~/.zenmap/zenmap.conf
```

**4. Compile and install**

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

**5. Run Zenmap**

For full functionality of Zenmap, it is recommended to be run as root.

```
$ sudo -i zenmap
```

That's about it! Happy nmapping!!!

Answer (score 1):

On 20.04 I didn't need python-gtk.

**First**, I installed the build dependencies for nmap:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt build-dep nmap
```

**Then**, downloaded (cloned) the source from github:

```
cd
git clone https://github.com/nmap/nmap.git
```

**Next**, change into the nmap directory:

```
cd nmap
```

**Finally**, configure, compile:

```
./configure
make
```

**Optionally**, install to the system:

```
sudo make install
```

---

**or instead of installing to the system:**

at this point, you could cd into the `~/nmap/zenmap` directory and then run zenmap:

```
cd zenmap
sudo -i ./zenmap
```

or:

```
sudo -i ~/nmap/zenmap/zenmap
```

Or, create an alias for `sudo -i`  as `sudoi` and `zenmap`:

```
echo alias sudoi=\"sudo -i \" >> ~/.bashrc
echo alias zenmap=\"/home/$USER/nmap/zenmap/zenmap\" >> ~/.bashrc
```

source your bashrc file to apply the changes:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

and then you can run zenmap with sudo:

```
sudoi zenmap
```

Comment: Worked ok on ubuntu 23.10 like a charm. I can't be more grateful for your kind answer.

Answer (score 0):

See Just_Alex's answer at [How to install Mendeley on Ubuntu 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405042/how-to-install-mendeley-on-ubuntu-22-04) which starts with `When installing Mendeley on Ubuntu 22.04 I was met with the following Error :`.

Just_Alex references a detailed answer on https://serverfault.com/a/383958 to remove the `python` dependency from the `python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb`.

Once you've removed the dependency and repackaged the .deb, you'll need to wget the cairo and gobject-2 .debs.

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pycairo/python-cairo_1.16.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygobject-2/python-gobject-2_2.28.6-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Finally, install the three .debs (remember, `python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb` must be updated and re-packaged first):

```
sudo dpkg -i python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb python-cairo_1.16.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb python-gobject-2_2.28.6-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

After that, you should be able to proceed with installing/running Zenmap.

Comment: This doesn't work. You need to compile from source for now as nmap is updating zenmap to python3. see my answer :)