# Makefile:372: install-zenmap Error 1

Tags: makefile

help please
followed instructions get this error

[Makefile:372: install-zenmap] Error 1

is there a fix

Comment: Which instructions? Please provide more details about what you are trying to do, and also your operating system

Comment: i want to install zenmap.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1421263/cant-install-zenmap-on-ubuntu-22-04-due-to-dependency-issues

Comment: What is your version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Which all steps of that answer did you follow? Where did you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, looks like this issue is still opened, here:
https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/2714
I have the same :(

upd: Successfully bypassed this error by downgrading `setuptools` to 62.0.0
First step:

```
sudo pip install setuptools==62.0.0

    error: externally-managed-environment
```

Python barks at you. Fixed by:

```
cd /usr/lib/python3.11
sudo rm EXTERNALLY-MANAGED
```

As been described here: https://www.makeuseof.com/fix-pip-error-externally-managed-environment-linux/

Second:

```
sudo pip install setuptools==62.0.0
```

And then you can check `setuptools` version with:

```
pip show setuptools
```

Worked for me.